# Manual Ubercart Views Taxonomy Order (D6)

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, ubercart

Client wants the parent taxonomy view page to be ordered in a manual arrangement just based on his belief of which products are most popular (this isn't a field in the database; nor do we have this information in the database).

Is there anyway to order the view page based on a weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using taxonomy manager: http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager

Allows you to setup weights for Taxonomy Terms easily and quickly.

I then had to adjust the view to sort terms by Taxonomy weights in order to order the terms accordingly in my views.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [draggable views](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews). Create a view of the taxonomy terms you're interested in sorted by the draggable field, and the clients can reorder on a display which also shows that field (they also need the permission IIRC).